# Isomorphic ReactJS - how to share code for both server side and client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, isomorphic

I use express.js and react.js for a small test. Below is my react code:

views/Todo.jsx,

```
var React = require('react');

var TodoApp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            counter: 0
        };
    },

    increment: function() {
        this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter+1 });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (<div>
            <div>{this.state.counter}</div>
            <button onClick={this.increment}>Increment!</button>
        </div>);
    }
});

module.exports = TodoApp;
```

But the `counter` is never increased when the button is clicked. the `increment` function is never been called.

Why? What have I done wrong?

**EDIT:**

The HTML output on my browser:

```
<html><head></head>
    <body><div class="container">
         <div>0</div>
         <button>Increment!</button>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see that there is no js in the html header at all. Is it becos of this? I render the HTML with react.js on the server side.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var reactViews = require('express-react-views');
var app = express();

// View engine setup.
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jsx');
app.engine('jsx', reactViews.createEngine());

// Set root.
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

// Get routes.
var todo = require('./routes/todo');

// Respond with "todo" app on the todo page.
app.use('/todo', todo);

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

routes/router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.render('Todo', {}); // 'Todo' is 'views/Todo.jsx'
});

module.exports = router;
```

I think the problem is the react is not shared between client side and the server side. currently it works on server side only. how and what can I do so that it is shared and it works on client side as well?

Any ideas?

Comment: just change your button to this <button onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>Increment!</button>

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my code. please see my edit above.

Comment: Yes you right ! see this example https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working fine check the below fiddle

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/56ppsy4v/][1]
```

Comment: I don't have this `ReactDOM.render(
  <TodoApp name="Test" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);` bcos I render the HTML with react on the server side. please see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={this.increment}>Increment!</button>
```

Should be

```
<button onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>Increment!</button>
```